# Minimum number of equilateral triangles in a parallelogram

Tags: geometry

If the two adjacent sides of a parallelogram are in the ratio 17:12 and the sum of a pair of opposite angles of the parallelogram is 120 degrees, find the minimum number of equilateral triangles (not necessarily all of the same size) into which the parallelogram can be exactly cut.

---

My attempt :-

I took the dimensions of the parallelogram to be 17 cm and 12 cm for the analysis

[image]

I don't understand how do we find the mimumum number of equilateral triangles over here, what I can infer is that there will be 2 largest equilateral triangles (AED and CFB) which will have side lengths of 12 cm each.  How do we proceed from here ? The solution provided by the author isn't clear to me, that expression is not making sense to me

---

**Solution as per the author:-**

[image]

Comment: FWIW The solution only establishes that 14 is doable, but not that 14 is indeed the minimum. $\quad$ The idea (unproven claim) is that by using the largest equilateral triangle at both ends to reduce the parallelogram into another parallelogram, we will use the minimum number of triangles.

Comment: Can you simplify the idea please, I am still not able to understand what does these 14 triangles mean , and what do we need to find exactly in the question

Comment: You have an inner parallelogram that has sides of $5$ and $12$.  Now cut equilateral triangles off each end.  You will be left with a yet smaller parallelogram.  What are its sides?  Keep going.  Eventually you will cut the entire central parallelogram into triangles and be done.  You should have $14$ of them.

Comment: Thank you that 14 makes sense after drawing the diagram, but why exactly are we trying to cut a parallelogram into another parallelogram ?

Comment: We are using a greedy algorithm to cut off the largest equilateral triangles we can at each stage.  We notice that makes another parallelogram that we apply the same algorithm to.  As Calvin Lin points out this shows that $14$ triangles are sufficient but does not show that there is no other configuration that results in a smaller number of triangles.  This approach will conclude with the smallest triangle having a side of the GCD of the original two sides, which is $1$ in this case.

Answer (score 1):

**Claim 1:** A parallelogram $ABCD$ can be tiled (covered without overlap except for edges) with equilateral triangles only if its angles are $60$ and $120$ degrees.

*Proof:* WLOG assume that $\angle A=\angle C\leq \angle B=\angle D$. Note that $\angle A+\angle B=180^\circ$. Now the tip $A$ of the parallelogram must be covered by some equilateral triangle, meaning that $A$ must be the vertex of at least $1$ equilateral triangle. Thus $\angle A\geq 60^\circ$. If there are two distinct equilateral triangles with vertex $A$, then $\angle A\geq 120^\circ$, contradicting the fact that $\angle A \leq \angle B$ and $\angle A+\angle B=180^\circ$. Thus $\angle A=60^\circ$ and $\angle B=120^\circ$ necessarily.

**Claim 2:** Let $ABCD$ be a parallelogram with $\angle A=\angle C=60^\circ$ and $\angle B=\angle D=120^\circ$ such that $[AD]=[BC]=1$ and $[AB]=[CD]=n$ for some natural number $n\geq 1$. Then the 'minimal tiling by equilateral triangles' for $ABCD$ is achieved with $2n$ triangles of side-length $1$.

*Proof:* Induction. When $n=1$, it is easy to see that we need at least $2$ triangles. When going from $n$ to $n+1$, note that the largest possible triangles we could use in the tiling cannot have side-length strictly greater than $1$. The area of $ABCD$ is easily seen to be $(n+1)\tfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ and the area of an equilateral triangle of side-length at most $1$ is at most $\tfrac{\sqrt{3}}{4}$. The conclusion is now immediate.

**Claim 3:** Let $ABCD$ be a parallelogram with $\angle A=\angle C=60^\circ$ and $\angle B=\angle D=120^\circ$. Let, as in the picture from the post, $E\in[AB]$ and $F\in[CD]$ be such that $DE$ is the bisector of $\angle ADC$ and $BF$ is the bisector of $ABC$. Assume that we know that the minimum number of equilateral triangles needed to cover the parallelogram $EBFD$ is already known and it is $N$ for some natural $N$. Then the minimal tiling of $ABCD$ will have $N+2$ triangles.

*Proof:* It is trivial to see that $\triangle ADE$ along with $\triangle CBF$ and the minimal covering for $EBFD$ achieves the $N+2$ covering for $ABCD$. But can we do better? The only attempt is to have $D'\in [AD]$ and $E'\in[AE]$ such that $\triangle AD'E'$ is equilateral and similar for $\triangle CB'F'$. This means that we are looking for a covering with less than $N$ triangles for the hexagon $D'E'BB'F'D$. Let us consider the trapezoid $D'E'ED$ which lies inside this hexagon. Such a 'smaller' cover of the hexagon cannot admit a subcover that covers $D'E'ED$ without excess since then we could split the hexagon cover into a cover for $D'E'ED$, one for $BB'F'F$ and one for $EBFD$ and this will definitely have more than $N$ triangles.

*not rigurous!!:* Since the angles of the trapezoid are multiples of $60^\circ$, the sides of the triangles that form this hypothetical subcover of $D'E'ED$ with excess must be parallel to the sides of the trapezoid. If we believe this, the only hope to get a smaller cover for the hexagon is if the excess from covering $D'E'ED$ that 'spills' into $EBFD$ will be a union of equilateral triangles. But then, we will definitely need at least $N$ triangles to cover the hexagon, so we are not finding a cover with less than $N+2$ triangles for $ABCD$.

**Claim 4:** Let $ABCD$ be a parallelogram with $\angle A=\angle C=60^\circ$ and $\angle B=\angle D=120^\circ$ such that $[AD]=[BC]=m$ and $[AB]=[CD]=n$ for some natural numbers $m<n$ that are coprime. Then the 'minimal tiling by equilateral triangles' for $ABCD$ is achieved with a number of equilateral triangles equal to $2$ times the number of steps in the 'Euclidean algorithm by subtraction' applied to the pair $(n,m)$.

*Proof:* To clarify what is meant, consider for example the 'Euclidean algorithm by subtraction' for the pair $(17,12)$. This will look like $(17,12)\rightarrow (12,5) \rightarrow (7,5)\rightarrow (5,2)\rightarrow(3,2)\rightarrow (2,1) \rightarrow (1,1)$. It is easy to see that this will correspond to the proposed solution by contracting multiple steps where the role of numerator and denominator does not flip, e.g., the two steps $(12,5)$ and $(7,5)$ can be condensed into $\left\lfloor \tfrac{12}{5}\right\rfloor$.

Again we will proceed by a sort of induction or descent along the steps of the 'Euclidean algorithm by division'. Crucially, since $m$ and $n$ are coprime, this will always terminate in $(1,1)$ and, in fact, the last steps $(q,1)\rightarrow\dots\rightarrow(1,1)$ are already covered by Claim 2.

The step case is covered (although not very formally) by Claim 3.

Comment: Just as a short remark. The not very formal part in Claim 3 can be made precise. The idea is to show that any covering with equilateral triangles of $D'E'ED$ would have all triangles with a side parallel to $[ED]$. This can be done by starting with the cover of the edge $D'E'$ by induction. This indeed means that the 'excess' will be an equilateral triangle 'spilling over' into $EDFB$. This shows that any tiling of the hexagon will indeed require at least (in fact more than) $N$ triangles, finishing the proof of Claim 3.